# Create search bar in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to create this in jetpack compose
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZpF7.png)

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: I'm confused and I can't create this

Comment: This is a very simple composable to make, nothing confusing. Please check out Google's codelabs on Jetpack Compose [here](https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-compose/course) for help and tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below steps:

- Create a `Row` with fillMaxWidth modifier.
- Inside it, there will be 2 composables: `TextField`, `Button`/`IconButton`
- Provide a weight modifier to the TextField with value `1f`.
- Next, provide a Button or IconButton composable with your search icon.